# When sending multiple messages to a Node.js tcp socket, they get streamed as a single message

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp

To show a simple example, I want to send multiple messages to a node.js tcp socket.  I only want to send the second message when the first message is fully sent/drained.  However, even when waiting for the write callback to be invoked, the messages seem to be sent as one message.

Here is some sample code:

```
var net = require('net');

var server = net.createServer();

server.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.write('First Message', function(){
    socket.write('Second Message')
  })
})

var client = new net.Socket();
client.setEncoding('utf8');

server.listen(9999, function(){
  client.connect(9999);
});

client.on('data', function(data){
  console.log('data received on socket:\n' + data);
});
```

According to the node.js documentation from socket.write, "The optional callback parameter will be executed when the data is finally written out - this may not be immediately."

Based on this, in my code the second message should only be sent when the data is finally written out for the first message.

But the written output is:

> data received on socket:
>
> First MessageSecond Message

How can I get it to send these messages separately?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

TCP does not send messages "separately". TCP is a *stream* protocol, which means that when you write bytes to the socket, you get the same bytes in the same order at the receiving end. There is no notion of "message boundaries" or "packets" anything of the sort.

In your example, the callback is called when the socket layer accepts your data for transmission. It does *not* mean that the data has been successfully sent, or even that it has left your computer at all. In your callback, you send a second message, but the socket layer combines that with the first message for efficiency because it doesn't matter to TCP.

Comment: This is correct.  However, for completeness, you might also want to learn about TCP's Nagle algorithm (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle's_algorithm), which bunches up small writes into larger ones for performance reasons.

You can disable this in node with socket.setNoDelay (https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_setnodelay_nodelay).

You SHOULD NOT rely on this for delineation of message boundaries, in part because you can't tell if some "smart" network device is going to do this upstream from you.

Comment: @JoeHildebrand: Yes, I'm aware of nagling. That is the primary reason why TCP connections should be treated as a stream of bytes and not as messages with boundaries.

Comment: Sorry, that comment was edited in a rush after I hit enter too quickly.  I didn't mean to imply that you didn't know about Nagle, but that folks who come along later might find setNoDelay interesting -- and to reinforce that even if they found it interesting, it doesn't help them. :)

Comment: @JoeHildebrand: Indeed, that's a good point to remind people of. Thanks.

Answer (score 23):

You need to define a format for your message, so that your client can determine the beginning and end of a message within the socket stream. For instance, you could use a carriage return to mark the end of a message in your example.

Then you could use a split stream to read the messages separately in the client.

```
var net = require('net');
var split = require('split');
var server = net.createServer();

server.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.write('First Message\n', function(){
    socket.write('Second Message\n')
  })
})

var client = new net.Socket();
client.setEncoding('utf8');

server.listen(9999, function(){
  client.connect(9999);
});

var stream = client.pipe(split());
stream.on('data',function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Worth noting that if you are reacting to events / sending packets on both the client and the server, you will need to split on both the client and the server. Great example!