# NodeJS Net server truncate messages

Tags: javascript, node.js, tcp

I have that simple server with net module

```
const net = require("net");
const port = 7070;
const host = "127.0.0.1";

const server = net.createServer();
server.listen(port, host, () => {
  console.log("TCP Server is running on port " + port + ".");
});

server.on("connection", function (sock) {
  sock.on("data", function (data) {
     console.log(data);
  });
});
```

it looks accept a message with some length limit, after increasing that limit, it truncate the message

for example, if the limit is 5
and I sent ABC12345

the server will receive ABC12 only

any idea how to increase that limit

I'm sending the message into a server deployed in AWS

---

I tried to send a test message with a numbers from 0 till 999,
it does not send the whole message as shown in the below screenshots

The first log

[image]

The second log

[image]

Comment: There is no inherent limit in the server you show. Maybe its in your client instead? I think you also need to add the client you use to send the message. Also, the server is listening on 127.0.0.1 only so you need to add something around it in order to be reachable from outside in AWS. Please provide also the relevant information about this  AWS setup.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I added more info with screenshots

Comment: Yes, please show client code.   TCP has flow control on sending so perhaps you're ignoring that.

Comment: Also, TCP will on it's own, decide what bundles to package the data in so you may send one block in the client and receive more than one block on the server.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When sending multiple messages to a Node.js tcp socket, they get streamed as a single message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24113273/when-sending-multiple-messages-to-a-node-js-tcp-socket-they-get-streamed-as-a-s)

Comment: You are assuming that TCP has a concept of a message. This assumption is wrong. With each event you might only get part of the data which were sent or even data from multiple sends together. You have to explicitly define and implement message semantics in your application if you need messages.

Comment: *" it does not send the whole message"* - it does not really help to show what was sent wrongly if you don't provide the code which does the sending.

Comment: I use a low-level library in MQL (MetaTrader) which send these messages

Comment: @SteffenUllrich By the way the issue is not related to the client side, as I have the same server locally, and it receive the whole message without issue

Comment: *"as I have the same server locally,"* - The  MTU on localhost is greater than on ethernet, which results in large "messages" split way earlier into fragments on ethernet than on localhost.  It also means that a single send might be able to send a single "message" at once on localhost, while sending only part on ethernet. If the message gets much larger you will get the same effect on localhost. Again, TCP is just a byte stream and you cannot assume that a single send will have a single matching receive.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich If that's the case, what do you think should I do, to keep the whole message sent in the remote server (ethernet)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252387/discussion-between-steffen-ullrich-and-ahmed-mohsen).

Answer (score 0):

#### Make sure the `highWaterMark` of `sock` is not very low

Usually it defaults to ~16MB, but it is possible that something is making it default to a lower value in your case.

Try this:

```
server.on("connection", function (sock) {
  console.log("sock.readableHighWaterMark =",sock.readableHighWaterMark)
  sock.writableHighWaterMark = 2_000_000; // This will give you 2 million bytes in one go
  sock.on("data", function (data) {
     console.log(data);
  });
});
```

Comment: I only have readableHighWaterMark and writableHighWaterMark, maybe because of a different node versions?

Comment: OK try reading the readable, and writing the writable!

Comment: Here's the log

> sock.readableHighWaterMark = 16384
> Caught exception: TypeError: Cannot set property writableHighWaterMark of #<Duplex> which has only a getter